# How to select a subset of rows and columns from a data.frame

Tags: r

I have this

```
d[d$Age > "2", ]
```

and it returns all the rows that have an Age of over 2, but I want to only return the values in a few of the columns, say d$X and d$Y, not all of them.

anyway i can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
d[d$Age > "2", c("X","Y")]
```

Answer (score 5):

Other way

```
subset(d, Age > "2", select=c(X, Y))
```