# Subsetting a DataFrame with a List

Tags: r, list, subset

I am trying to use a random list of sample IDs generated in R as the basis to subset a larger dataframe. I realize that I can just randomly subset directly but I'd like to know in case next time I need to subset using specific sample names.

I have data (mydata) that looks like this:

```
Species.Obj.ID  Sample  Sample.Name
1                23      George
2                90      Adilade
3                34      Frank
4                23      Steve
```

I generated random numbers

```
rand<-sample(1:4, 2, replace=F)
```

Then tried to subset the data using the example from here ([How to filter a table's row based on an external list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584597/r-how-to-filter-a-tables-row-based-on-an-external-list)).

```
subset(mydata,subset= Species.Obj.ID %in% rand)
```

But I just get back the full original data (mydata) in return.

I'd like to get the rows in the datatable from the random numbers in rand.

I'd greatly appreciate any advice on how to correct this. Thanks!

Comment: is that a typo? `Sample.Obj.ID` or `Species.Obj.ID` ?

Comment: Sorry about that it was. Corrected.

Comment: I ran the code and it works. Are you missing something? Also use `set.seed` for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way is a bit easier than using `subset`

```
> yourData <- data.frame(Species.Obj.ID = 1:4, 
                         Sample = c(23,90,34,23), 
                         Sample.Name = c("George", "Adilade", "Frank", "Steve"))

> rand <- sample(1:4, 2, replace = FALSE)

> rand
[1] 2 3  # the random numbers are 2 and 3

> yourData[rand, ]  # the rows shown are rows 2 and 3

  Species.Obj.ID Sample Sample.Name
2              2     90     Adilade
3              3     34       Frank
```

You can even shorten this all by using

```
yourData[sample(1:4, 2, replace = FALSE), ]
```

This will return a random sample of 2 rows of your original data.